# github: How to list all remote and local branches but without the branches for pull requests?

Tags: git, github

Now GitHub will create a hidden branch for each pr, like /pr/1, which can be seen when "git branch -a" on a local clone, but hidden at GitHub UI.

I still want to preserve these branches, but I don't want to see them when I "git branch -a" on my shell (just too many). Anyone know how to do that?

Comment: `git branch --list <pattern>` support wildcard but probably not extglob like in bash, thus I guess you'll need an shell aliased using grep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a pattern with `git branch --list pattern`. The `pattern` uses unix shell globbing.

I.E. To avoid to list branches like `pr/*` such as `pr/1`, `pr/2`, etc, use command as follows.

```
git branch -a --list {'[!p]*','p[!r]*','pr[!/]*'}
```

Or you can use `grep` to filter your results to avoid the complicated pattern.

```
git branch -a | grep -v 'pr/*'
```

Comment: Yeah, grep is always your friend. :)